# A obj(obj), What's happening behind the scenes?

Tags: c++, constructor

I was writing a simple program to show different types of constructors available in C++(default, parametrized, and copy). When I encountered this problem(if that's right to say it a problem). What I'm posting here isn't the actual program but it is a part of the main program.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
        public:
                A (A&)
                {
                        cout << "copy ctor of A.\n";
                }
                ~A ()
                {
                        cout << "dtor of A\n";
                }
};

int main()
{
        A obj(obj);
        return 0;
}
```

So my question here is:

1. What means `A obj(obj);` here?
2. How copy constructor is taking reference to an object which even doesn't exist in the memory?

Comment: `A obj(obj);` has the same meaning as `A obj = obj;`.  Something the language still allows, but is almost certainly a typo.

Comment: @DrewDormann But how is it working?

Comment: @DrewDormann I got the answer to Q1. What about Q2?

Comment: Consider that, inside your constructor, `this` represents a pointer to an object that has not yet been constructed.  It is a pointer to an object that, in your words, "even doesn't exist".  The `A&` passed to the constructor is a reference to that same memory.